# How do I win level 5 (Grey Void) in Eufloria?

Tags: eufloria

I have colonized every landmass on the level and have 3 trees on each. All of them have capped at 40 seedlings, so there's nothing left to do. How do I win this level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About midway through the level, you gain the ability to plant Defense Trees.  Are you planting any of these?  I think one of the requirements to clear the level is having a few of these, although I don't know what the exact quantity is (2, I think?).

Here's the popup:

At about a minute past this bookmark, the player gets a second popup saying "Excellent, you have planted several DEFENSE TREES..."

Comment: I did not plant any of these, as they were not strategically important on this basic level. Is there any way to replace my other trees with defense trees or must I start over?

Comment: No, I don't think you can delete trees, you'll likely have to start the level over :(

Answer (score 2):

You can unlock the next set of levels so you can just skip lv 5.  For me it was that or uninstall.  Not going to replay a level because of I didn't plant enough of a certain type of tree and can't replace old ones sigh.  What an oversight.

Comment: On the other hand, not being able to follow basic intructions is clearly NOT a flaw on your part...